# Is this a good programming practice in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
class A
  attr_accessor :m

  def n
    @m + 1
  end
end

a = A.new
a.m = 4
p a.n
```

I'm talking about the code inside the "n" method where you have @m + 1. Is this kind of code prone to crash because I haven't required the user to give value to the @m variable?

Comment: Why won't you define an initialize method and set the value of @m to 0 to avoid the risk of crashing?

Comment: If I remove m, it works. However, if I do m = m + 1, the program crashes. However, self.m = m + 1 works. :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, attributes should have default values when appropriate, or the value should be passed into the constructor. In the case of the above, if you removed the `a.m = 4` line and run the code, you get this error:

```
some.rb:5:in `n': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from some.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

For objects, if attributes *don't* have a default value, require that they be passed in via the constructor and fail if they are not. That ensures that no matter how the object is instantiated, you'll have a sane default value there. Passing around an object with an exposed value like that is a ticking time bomb in the code.

Comment: Besides having a default value, the other option is raising an exception with an explanatory error message.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things slightly disturbing about your code:

1. You should reference values set with `attr_accessor` by their variable name and not their instance variable name, that means do this

   ```
   def n
     m + 1 # and not @m + 1
   end
   ```
2. If a variable can be `nil`, you should guard all operations involving it against `nil` somehow, even if it means raising a custom error, since "undefined method + for NilClass" is not a really descriptive error. That means it would be better to write something like this

   ```
   def n
     raise StandardError.new("m is not set in instance of A") if m.nil?
     m + 1
   end
   ```

   This will save you time if you're going to hunt for bugs. Also, you can use default values for `m` if you have one, but rather set it on initialization then:

   ```
   def initialize
     super()
     self.m = 3 #or
     # self.m ||= 3 This would only set m if it wasn't set by initialization in a superclass
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use setter based dependency injection when the properties are optional or not required for building the objects, use constructor based dependency injection when the property is required for building the object (or its key functionality).

In your case if the only thing objects of your class would do is to call method `n` then use a constructor to provide `m` else use a setter